# Netlogo list in list iterations with counter

Tags: list, iteration, netlogo

I have read from csv a list of lists named fileList [[id, id2, id3],[10,10,11]]
But i have problem that I want to iterate trough the list and in every iteration create a turtle that contain id1, id3 (not Id2) as variables. My idea in python syntax (I need help to transpose it to NetLogo):

```
for x, list in enumerate(fileList):
       if x==0: #first list is names so I transpose the names to places in
           index_id=list.index(id) 
           index_id3=list.index(id3)
       else:
           create-turtle_nr1 #not in python syntax but the idea is to create turte to assign variables from list below  
           ask turtle_nr1 [set id1 item (item as list[index_id])]
```

Overall output is three turtles with variables id and id3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should just be able use `item` to index your lists iteratively. Essentially, for each turtle you want it to index the appropriate list-of-variables from the list of lists and then index the appropriate variable from *that* list. You could start with something like:

```
turtles-own [
   id
   id2
   id3
]

to list-of-lists

  ;;; these lists are just placeholders, of course, use your real list of lists
  ;;; as the "ids_list" variable in this case
  let id1list [ 1 2 3]    
  let id2list [ 44 55 66 ]
  let id3list [ "a" "b" "c" ]
  let ids_list ( list id1list id2list id3list )

  let n 0

  while [ n < 3 ] [  ;;; or however many turtles you end up wanting, 
                     ;;; as long as you have list variables for them 
    create-turtles 1 [
      set id item n (item 0 ids_list)
      set id3 item n (item 2 ids_list)
    ]
    set n n + 1
  ]

end
```

This procedure creates three turtles with ids of 1, 2, and 3, id2s of 0, and id3s of a, b, and c.